# Triple Integral (Inequality sign help)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Calculate the integral:
$$\int \:\int \:\int \:z\sqrt{x^2+y^2}dxdydz$$
over the area 
A = {$(x,y,z): x^2+(y-1)^2 \ge 1$ and $0 \le z \le 2$}

I have managed to set up the integral correctly like this:

$$\int _0^2\:\:\int _0^{\pi}\:\int _0^{2\cdot \:sin\left(\theta \right)}\:z\cdot \:r^2\:dr\:d\theta \:dz$$

$r \ge2\cdot sin(\theta)$ is the radius bigger than a small circle just above origo. Why do I in the equation above integrate just the small circle when the inequality asks me to integrate anything bigger than the small circle just above the origo? I can't understand how this can be the case, so I guess the inequality sign must change direction somehow, but where in all this does the inequality change its direction? Or what am I misunderstanding if this is not the case?

It must be:

$r \le2\cdot sin(\theta)$

Comment: $x^2 + (y-1)^2 \color{red}{\ge} 1$?  Isn't that an infinite region?  That itself is fine, but I don't think the integral of $z\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ will converge.  Should that be $\le 1$ in the original problem statement, perhaps?

Comment: @tilper I have double checked. It is written as I wrote it above, in the original problem. I know that my integral is correct because I got the right answer. If you think the original problem is wrong, maybe you are right.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like there's a typo in the problem you were given.

Comment: What is the answer you found ?. @tilper pointed out correctly the divergence.